# OpenCV BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 algorithm crashes when executed as part of my Swift UI app

Tags: opencv, swiftui, exc-bad-access, background-subtraction

I'm creating a `Swift UI` application to process images on a device and use the `OpenCV` library, specifically the [BackgroundSubtractor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html) algorithm. I was able to follow the [OpenCV iOS guide](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/def/tutorial_image_manipulation.html) and perform basic image operations, like take an image, convert to Matrix, make it gray or perform bitwise operations with OpenCV functions but when I try to use the BackgroundSubtractor.apply method, the app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error:

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10455aa40)`

Here is my code:

```
+ (UIImage *)toMyGreatImage:(UIImage *)source {
    
    Mat sourceMat = [OpenCVWrapper _matFrom:source];
    Mat result;
    
    BackgroundSubtractor *backSub = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
    Mat mask;
    backSub->apply(sourceMat, mask); // crashes here
    return [OpenCVWrapper _imageFrom:mask];
}
```

Just to compare, my other function works perfectly fine with the same source image:

```
+ (UIImage *)toGray:(UIImage *)source {
    return [OpenCVWrapper _imageFrom:[OpenCVWrapper _grayFrom:[OpenCVWrapper _matFrom:source]]];
}
```

I have also tested the background subtractor code in python and it works as expected. What did I miss in my iOS setup?

Comment: `BackgroundSubtractor *backSub = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();` dont use a *raw* pointer ! you need a refcounted `Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> backSub = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();`  else your newly created instance is DOA

Comment: Indeed! In my case Ptr<> was ambiguous and no candidates were suggested so I just went with the regular pointer. After your clarification switch to cv::Ptr<> and to works. Thanks for the help. Please post as an answer so I can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a "smart pointer" to capture your newly created BackgroundSubtractor instance (not a "raw" one), else it will self-destruct, and crash when you call a method on an invalid pointer:

```
cv::Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> backSub = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
```

(note, that `cv::Ptr` is just an alias for `std::shared_ptr` nowadays)

(also, [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html))